# ArcGIS Javascript - Editor API methods?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing

I was looking at the API for the ArcGIS [Editor widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/editor.html) (esri.dijit.editing.Editor), and I couldn't find a list of methods that are on the widget. I've seen [other examples](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/32368-Start-Stop-Editor-Widget) online that call destroy(), but that method isn't listed.  Where can I find a complete listing of the Editor's methods?